# dynamic custom tree access

Tags: c#, tree, composite

I'm looking to access and edit the following tree structure and can't find a good way on the interwebs.

```
class SimpleNode
{
    string Name;
    SimpleType Type;
    List<SimpleList> Children;
}

class SimpleList
{
    //some list-based properties
    List<SimpleNode> Items;
}
```

I need to be able to look up and edit nodes without resorting to:

```
Node.Children[0].Items[0].Children[1].Items[3]
```

or the like.  I attempted this via a function that returned an element of the tree, but editing the returned element didn't seem to affect the actual tree.  Adding to the complexity is that I don't want to preclude two identical nodes to exist in different points in the tree.

As is obvious, this is my first time with a tree structure and could really use some help.

---

Upon further investigation (per Drew), the composite pattern concept makes sense, espcially the method forwarding/aggregate return concepts.  The trick here is that I might have two Nodes with identical identifiers (Type & Name) at two different points in the tree.

The code that didn't work was something like (it's long gone):

```
Node GetNode(Type type, string name)
{ // returns node }
```

I tried something like:

```
Node nodeToEdit = GetNode(params);
nodeToEdit.Name = "New Name";
```

or

```
nodeToEdit.Children.Add(new Node());
```

but it didn't seem to take in the tree.  If it should have, let me know because I must have missed something.

Comment: are the elements classes or structs?

Comment: Could you elaborate upon what you mean by 'edit'? What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: This is known as the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). I suggest you read up on it and then extend your question.

Comment: If you want to look up and edit values by key, why not use a `Dictionary`, `SortedDictionary` or `SortedSet`?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: By edit, I mean I want to change the name or other properties of the Nodes and Lists. I'll also look up Composite Patterns.  Thanks for not discounting me.
Will edit when I have more info.

Comment: @SWeko: classes (at least for now)

Comment: No worries. Data structures are fun and powerful when used well. Working with trees nearly always ends up with 'walking' the tree. You could research _depth first traversal_ and _breadth first traversal_. These are two very similar and simple concepts. You might use them to find a node in your tree that has a certain Name, for example.

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample code that has the problem?

Comment: Pseudocode posted above.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As also stated in the comments, when working with trees you sooner or later end up walking the tree and performing actions on the items. Typically, you use some sort of recursive function that receives a node as a parameter and calls itself with the children.

In your sample, there are two kinds of items in the tree that do not share a common interface. This adds some complexity as you have to inspect two types of items.

A simple function to walk the tree is shown in the sample below. The method receives a node as a parameter and the level of the node. Also, there are two callbacks: one for the `SimpleNode` items and another that is called for the `SimpleList` items. As the process of walking the tree is the same, you can share this code and provide specific methods that handle the elements of the tree for a scenario.

```
void TreeWalk(SimpleNode node, int level, Action<SimpleNode, int> inspectNode, Action<SimpleList, int> inspectList)
{
    if (node == null)
        return;
    if (inspectNode != null)
        inspectNode(node, level);
    foreach(var simpleLst in node.Children)
    {
        if (inspectList != null)
            inspectList(simpleLst, level + 1);
        foreach(var child in simpleLst.Items)
            TreeWalk(child, level + 2, inspectNode, inspectList);
    }
}
```

As a node is required, the methods first validates the input parameter. Then it calls the callback method that can perform the action on the `SimpleNode`. Examples for such an action could be to change the node value if certain criteria are met.

The method then inspects the children of the node. First, it calls the callback method for the `SimpleList` items and afterwards iterates the `Items` of the `simpleList`. For each node, it calls itself again for the child. The level is also incremented.

The following sample shows how to change a node value if certain criteria are met. As there is no action to perform for the `SimpleList` items, `null` is used as parameter for the corresponding callback.

```
// Change node "11" to "11x"
var nameToLookFor = "11";
var newName = "11x";
TreeWalk(data, 0, 
    (node, level) => {
        if (node.Name == nameToLookFor)
            node.Name = newName;
    }, 
    null);
```

For testing reasons, it is helpful to print the contents of the tree. You can achieve this with another set of callback methods:

```
TreeWalk(root, 0, 
    (node, level) => Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', level * 2) + string.Format("Node: {0} - {1}", node.Name, node.Type)), 
    (list, level) => Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', level * 2) + "List"));
```